# Android RxJava2 App crashing on calling emitter.onError() from created observable

Tags: android, rx-java2

I am creating `Observable` manually with the help of `create()`. now inside, I check some conditions & based on that, I would like to notify the subscriber about error. Here's how I am creating observable:

```
public Observable<User> loginUser(String email, String password) {
    return Observable.create(
        emitter -> {
            myAsynchronousWork.onCompleteListener(
               result -> {
                   if(!result.isSuccess()) {
                      // This causes the crash.
                      emitter.onError(new Throwable(result.getError()));
                   } else {
                      // Process result & create User object & return it. This works as expected.
                      emitter.onNext(user);
                      emitter.onComplete();
                   }
               }
            );

        }
    );

}
```

& then I subscribe to `loginUser()` like:

```
loginUser("", "")
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(user -> {
                    Log.d("TAG", "logged in user => " + user.getUuid());
                    Log.d("TAG", "user name => " + user.getUserName());
                    Log.d("TAG", "user email => " + user.getEmailId());
                }, throwable -> {
                    Log.e("TAG", "error in login => " + throwable.getMessage());
                }, () -> {

                });
```

I expect that calling `emitter.onError()` should go inside onError of `subscribe()` of `loginUser()` where I have Logged the exception, but instead the app gets crashes with the Exception returned by `emitter.onError()` in logcat like there's no one to handle it!

I checked by debugging & found that while it's on line `emitter.onError()`, `emitter` was `"null"`. however onNext & onComplete doesn't cause any problem.
Please let me know where I am doing wrong?

Comment: provide the StackTrace for the error..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why my app was getting crashed was, I had actually something like this:

```
myAsynchronousWork.onCompleteListener(
               result -> {
                   if(!result.isSuccess()) {
                      // This causes the crash.
                      emitter.onError(new Throwable(result.getError()));
                   } else {
                      // Process result & create User object & return it. This works as expected.
                      emitter.onNext(user);
                      emitter.onComplete();
                   }
               },
               exception -> {
                   emitter.onError(exception); // This was the reason of problem!
               }
            );
```

I didn't posted the full part because I didn't get that it was causing the exception.

What happening here was, my code first was going inside the `exception->` part which was notifying the observer about the error & that observer was getting terminated. now my `result->` part was getting executed & here when I tried to call again `emitter.onError()`, it was crashing as there was no `emitter` to handle this & RxJava2 was throwing it globally.

So for me, I removed the `exception ->` part as it was any how going to be on `result ->` where I could check the result & I have also wrapped the emitter.onError with

```
if(!emitter.isDisposed()) emitter.onError();
```

because in my case, it was fine to ignore the error if emitter was disposed.

Comment: For anyone else that comes across this, you can rather use emitter.tryOnError(), which will check the disposed state to prevent the crash.

Answer (score 1):

Using `emitter.tryOnError` works for me and it will call error inside `subscribe()` as well without `UndeliverableException` or app stop running.

Answer (score -1):

When you are creating observable you have to handle all possible errors yourself. so your code should look something like below:

```
public Observable<User> loginUser(String email, String password) {
    return Observable.create(
        emitter -> {
          try{
            myAsynchronousWork.onCompleteListener(
               result -> {
                 try{
                   if(!result.isSuccess()) {
                      // This causes the crash.
                      emitter.onError(new Throwable(result.getError()));
                   } else {
                      // Process result & create User object & return it. This works as expected.
                      emitter.onNext(user);
                      emitter.onComplete();
                   }
                 }catch(Exception e){
                    emitter.onError(e);
                 }
               }
            );
         }catch(Exception e){
            emitter.onError(e);
        }

        }
    );

}
```

PS: Always ensure error checking when creating observable and disposable too.

Comment: This wouldn't solve the problem as the app was crashing while calling `emitter.onError()` it self.