# Fatal Exception: io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException java.lang.Throwable: UNAUTHORIZED / TOKEN_EXPIRED

Tags: java, twilio

I'm getting the errors below in crashlytics and I can't find a way to reproduce the error. They are aggregated by crashlytics as the same error but some devices fail because of `UNAUTHORISED` error and some fail because of `TOKEN_EXPIRED` error.

```
Fatal Exception: io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: java.lang.Throwable: UNAUTHORIZED
       at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:349)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableCreate$CreateEmitter.onError(ObservableCreate.java:74)
       at data.repositories.twilio_chat.TwilioChatRepository$6$1.onError(TwilioChatRepository.java:318)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.twilio.chat.internal.RethrowingForwarder$RethrowingProxy.invoke(RethrowingForwarder.java:121)
       at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
       at $Proxy17.onError()
       at com.twilio.chat.internal.CallbackListenerForwarder$2.run(CallbackListenerForwarder.java:47)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7660)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

and

```
Fatal Exception: io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: java.lang.Throwable: TOKEN_EXPIRED
       at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:349)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableCreate$CreateEmitter.onError(ObservableCreate.java:74)
       at data.repositories.twilio_chat.TwilioChatRepository$6$1.onError(TwilioChatRepository.java:318)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.twilio.chat.internal.RethrowingForwarder$RethrowingProxy.invoke(RethrowingForwarder.java:121)
       at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke(Proxy.java:1006)
       at $Proxy16.onError()
       at com.twilio.chat.internal.CallbackListenerForwarder$2.run(CallbackListenerForwarder.java:47)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8447)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:596)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

The code below shows where the error is coming from, I have added a comment for the stack trace that is showing line 318.

```
public Observable<List<ChannelDescriptor>> getChannelDescriptors() {
        return Observable.create(new ObservableOnSubscribe<List<ChannelDescriptor>>() {
            @Override
            public void subscribe(final ObservableEmitter<List<ChannelDescriptor>> emitter) throws Exception {
                Channels channels = chatClient.getChannels();
                channels.getUserChannelsList(new CallbackListener<Paginator<ChannelDescriptor>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Paginator<ChannelDescriptor> channelDescriptorPaginator) {
                        emitter.onNext(channelDescriptorPaginator.getItems());
                        emitter.onComplete();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(ErrorInfo errorInfo) { 
                        emitter.onError(new Throwable(errorInfo.getMessage())); //THIS IS LINE 318
                        super.onError(errorInfo);
                    }
                });
          
            }
        });
    }
```

I'm really confused as to what can cause the `CallbackListener` to cause an error while calling `onError` and crashes. This is the link to the docs for `CallbackListener`: https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/android/chat/releases/0.11.2/docs/com/twilio/chat/CallbackListener.html#onError-com.twilio.chat.ErrorInfo-

Comment: Could it be similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46421017/28376)?

Comment: That definitely helps. I couldn't reproduce the error so I just forced the error call in onSuccess and was able to replicate almost the exact same error. Changed ```emitter.onError``` to ```emitter.tryOnError``` seems to prevent the crash

Comment: That's good to hear. I'm not an Android developer, so I don't really know how to dig in to this. Glad you're making progress.